# html-to-image dependency not showing vuetify icons

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, wkhtmltoimage

I am using html-to-image 1.6.2 package to convert a html page to an image. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image) There when converting vuetify data table to an image it's pagination row have missing icons as follows.

[image]

As in the above image drop down arrow icon, navigation left and right arrow icons are missing. My code is as below.

```
var node = document.getElementById('my-node');

htmlToImage.toPng(node)
 .then(function (dataUrl) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = dataUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
})
.catch(function (error) {
   console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
});
```

So is there any way to get those missing icons in datatable? And html-to-image is missing to render any of the vuetify icons

Comment: Seems font for icons is not used to render the image.